# How to solve Hoffman & Kunze exercise 6, section 10.1

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let n be a positive integer, and let $V$ be the space of all nxn matrices over
>   the field of complex numbers. Show that the equation$$f(A,B)=ntr(AB)-tr(A)tr(B)$$
>
> defines a bilinear form $f$ on $V$. Is it true that $f(A,B)= f(B,A) \forall A,B$?

Is the following thing right?
$$f(\lambda A+C,B)=ntr((\lambda A+C)B)-tr(\lambda A+C)tr(B)$$
 $$=ntr((\lambda A+C)B)-tr(\lambda A+C)tr(B)$$ 
$$=ntr(\lambda AB)+ntr(CB)- \lambda tr(AB)-tr(CB)$$
$$=\lambda ntr(AB)+ ntr(CB)-\lambda tr(A)tr(B)- tr(C)tr(B)$$
$$=\lambda (ntr(AB)-tr(A)tr(B))+ntr(CB)-tr(C)tr(B)$$
$$=\lambda f(A,B)+f(C,B) $$

And I can say it is symmetric, so the last question is yes, it is true.

Comment: What you have shown isn't quite enough to show bilinearity in the second variable unless you already have symmetry. Of course, the computation for the second variable is exactly analogous so this is a minor quibble.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything you've done here is correct. You should prove that $f$ is symmetric using the fact that $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA)$ for all $A,B$.